# Linux shell script not giving any output

Tags: bash, shell

I have written the following script. It is not giving any error.

But it is also not creating any output file

```
for i in cat list
do
    a=awk '{if ($1 == "H") print $0;}' $i
    b=awk '{if ($1 == "D") print $0;}' $i
    c=$(wc -l < $i)
    d=expr $c - 1`
    e=sed -n '$c'p` 
    f=sed -n '$d'p`
    printf "$a $b $e $f\n" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: What is this: sed -n '$c'p`

Comment: Are your files called `cat` and `list` or do you want to read the files from a file called `list`? If the last, you should write: `for i in $(cat list)` or `while read i; do ... done < list`.  And there seem to be a few  `\`` characters missing from your script

Comment: The program you posted would cause a lot of errors. Please post your real code. Maybe you left out some backticks? (Why on earth would you do that? Copy-paste, it's easy!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command:

```
for i in cat list; do echo $i; done
```

Will just print `cat` and `list` as output.

If you just want to run for loop for each line of file `list` then use:

```
while read l
do
   echo "$i"
   # repalce echo with your actual script commands and keep "$i" in double quotes
done < list
```

Comment: Also `"$i"` should be in double quotes except under very specific circumstances which are hardly applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really had backticks where they are needed, and taking Anubhava's correction into account, the major remaining issue is that `sed` does not treat `$c` as the value of a shell variable - you need double quotes in this context to make the shell expand the value of the variable before `sed` sees it.

```
while read -r i; do
  a=$(awk '{if ($1 == "H") print $0;}' "$i")
  b=$(awk '{if ($1 == "D") print $0;}' "$i")
  c=$(wc -l < "$i")
  d=$(expr "$c" - 1)
  e=$(sed -n "${c}p")
  f=$(sed -n "${d}p")
  printf "$a $b $e $f\n"
done <file >>output.txt
```

Notice also the judicious use of double quotes around variable names, and the refactoring of the output redirection. If you mean to overwrite `output.txt` instead of appending, use a single `>`.

This is still not a pretty script, but without knowledge of the actual problem and the desired input and output, it's hard to say how to improve it. By the general looks of it, rewriting it entirely in Awk might be a good idea.